# how to upgrade a jhipster app generated with an old blueprint?

Tags: jhipster

I succeeded to create a simple blueprint for a jhipster app which changes the home.component.html file and also add a maven dependency. So i'm basically overloading the client generator and the server generator. Everything goes fine when i generate my jhipster app with this blueprint, the problem comes when i want to upgrade my jhipster app.
My blueprint version is 6.8.0,and so does my generated app. Now want to upgrade my app to 6.10.4 so i guess i should upgrade my blueprint to 6.10.4 first.

_ i didn't find a way to upgrade the blueprint **without** rewriting my changes

_ whats is the command line to upgrade with the new blueprint(ie 6.10.4)?    I tried(like the doc says):

**$ jhipster upgrade --verbose --target-blueprint-versions my-blueprint2@6.10.4** but i get an error:

```
ERROR! Error: Something went wrong while installing generator-jhipster-my-blueprint2!  npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: generator-jhipster-my-blueprint2@0.0.0
```

Comment: I suspect that version 6.10.4 does not exist for your blueprint, try using latest version of this particular blueprint.Also maybe  npm searches for your blueprint on a registry and you haven't copied it to a private one nor a public one.

Comment: sorry im new in node and npm. Are you saying that i have to put my blueprint in a private registry with npm?


But my more important question was about how to update a blueprint. I wanted to update my blueprint from  6.8 to 6.10.4 but didnt succeed...

Comment: You have 2 questions in one: updating your app with a blueprint, updating your blueprint. My suggestions are only for your app as I suspect that you have used only with `npm link` and I'm not sure it can work with `jhipster upgrade`. For the second one, I don't think there's any tool for it and more I don't think there's any documentation about what has changed regarding blueprints (if any)  in new JHipster changelogs You might want to open an issue for it.

Comment: What else could i use except `npm link` ? (i see nothing else in the documentation)

Comment: `npm link` is for development, the usual workflow is that once your blueprint is complete, it's supposed to be versioned and published to an npm registry. The key point is that `jhipster upgrade` executes `npm install` before generating the app twice: one in original version and one in the target version. In fact, it even does an `npm show` for blueprints, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/upgrade/index.js#L202-L212